# Iterate through path type inside 'WHERE' statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, for-loop, coordinates

I have a table defined as following

```
CREATE TABLE public.geometry_polyline_volume (
    id          serial not null primary key,
    distance    float not null,
    height      float not null,
    coordinates path not null );
```

Is there any way to iterate the *coordinates* in order to filter some specific points inside the *coordinates* ?
Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO rf.geometry_polyline_volume(id, distance, height, coordinates)
VALUES (1, 200, 600, path('(15.878137629895164,47.08306448089695), (14.56169808311181,47.219041634920686), (14.267442604782124,47.4201665137259), (14.092631384557304,47.71366328136526), (14.234428926980286,47.95865145177352)'));

INSERT INTO rf.geometry_polyline_volume(id, distance, height, coordinates)
VALUES (2, 200, 600, path('(15.878137629895164,47.08306448089695), (15.56169808311181,47.219041634920686), (15.267442604782124,47.4201665137259), (15.092631384557304,47.71366328136526), (15.234428926980286,47.95865145177352)'));
```

---

```
SELECT id 
    FROM public.geometry_polyline_volume 
    WHERE FOR coord in coordinates DO coord[0] > 15 END;
```

To return the row with id=2

Comment: A polyline is *one* object, not an array of points. Spatial indexes work on spatial objects, not individual coordinates. What is the *actual* spatial query you want to perform? Is it really 'lines north of the equator` ? Or are you trying to find lines that interset a specific area?

Comment: In any case, SQL is a set-based language. There's seldom any need for loops

Comment: I want to check if there is any intersection with a specific geographic rectangle

Comment: Check [Getting intersections the fast way](https://postgis.net/2014/03/14/tip_intersection_faster/). You need to use spatial operators like ST_Intersects etc.

Comment: @chatzich would to use PostGIS be an option for you?

Comment: @JimJones no our database does not support PostGIS due to its overhead